# SharePoint Equivalent formulas to: Index and Match

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am transferring an Excel Report to a List in SharePoint.  In Excel I have the following formula: **=INDEX(A1:L1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A3:L3<>0,),0))**

This formula is necessary for us to identify when is the Project Managers will have their projects with "First month with expense".

If you can help me it would be wonderful.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsRDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, calculating in the range of multiple columns is not available in the SharePoint.

As a workaround, you could filter items with value in a column.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emily Du - MSFT, thanks for your input.  
I won't be able to use the filtering option, unfortunately it is not the objective intended for the calculation result.  We are trying to find which month was the first one with expense, and based on that number we will calculate if other actions are "On Track" or "Delayed".

Answer (score 0):

Good morning everyone,
I was able to find the solution :)

=IF([JUN FY-ACTS]>0,"1",IF([JUL FY-FCST]>0,"2",IF([AUG FY-FCST]>0,"3",IF([SEP FY-FCST]>0,"4",IF([OCT FY-FCST]>0,"5",IF([NOV FY-FCST]>0,"6",IF([DEC FY-FCST]>0,"7",IF([JAN FY-FCST]>0,"8",IF([FEB FY-FCST]>0,"9",IF([MAR FY-FCST]>0,"10",IF([APR FY-FCST]>0,"11",IF([MAY FY-FCST]>0,"12","N/A"))))))))))))